# JavaScript got error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of undefined at init "

Tags: javascript, acumatica

I just want to disable the buttons when the page load but it got that error. It seems like it can't get the property of "getValue" or "value" something like that.

My code is:

```js
function init(){
 var ele = px_all["ctl00_phF_tab_t0_edStatus"].getValue();
 document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_edTImeClock").style.fontSize = "49px";
 document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_edTImeClock").style.height = "50px";
 document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_edTImeClock").style.padding = "0";
 document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_edTImeClock").style.borderBottom = "0";
 document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonStart").style.marginLeft = "10px";
 document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_edResult").style.padding = "0";
 
 if(ele == "CL" || ele == "CD"){
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonStart").setAttribute("disabled", "true");  
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonStart").classList.remove("ButtonH"); 
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonStart").classList.add("ButtonD"); 
  
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonPause").setAttribute("disabled", "true");  
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonPause").classList.remove("ButtonH"); 
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonPause").classList.add("ButtonD"); 
  
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonReset").setAttribute("disabled", "true");  
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonReset").classList.remove("ButtonH"); 
  document.getElementById("ctl00_phF_tab_t3_buttonReset").classList.add("ButtonD"); 
 }
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: This is not a good question to ask at SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Have a context or real problem you need help with!

Comment: What is `px_all["ctl00_phF_tab_t0_edStatus"]`? To get the content of a property you don't need `()`, just `.<propertyname>` (e.g. `px_all["ctl00_phF_tab_t0_edStatus"].value`)

Comment: even `px_all["ctl00_phF_tab_t0_edStatus"].value` doesn't work at all.

Comment: I think `px_all` is not in the scope at all

Comment: When I use that function on click button, it works smoothly but on window.onload didn't.

Comment: do a `typeof px_all` - is it coming `undefined` or `object`?

Comment: `px_all["ctl00_phF_tab_t0_edStatus"].getValue` is an object.

Comment: try `var ele = px_all["ctl00_phF_tab_t0_edStatus"].value`

Comment: it got the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be indexing 'edStatus'? px_all["edStatus"]

Comment: nothing changes.